# Specified cast is not valid. at System.Json.JsonValue in Xamarin rest service get method

Tags: c#, xamarin

My WepApi is sending correct formatted json data (e.g. `{"code":"200","status":"OK","message":"hello Sarker"}`) and code is

```
    [HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Login(int id)
{
  return Json(new { code = "200", status = "OK", message = "hello Sarker" });
}
```

In my RestService class in Xamarin fetch method is like

```
public async Task<JsonValue> FetchWebApiAsync(string url)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = "GET";
        try {

            using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {

                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {

                    JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc.ToString());


                    return jsonDoc;

                }
            }

        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            return null;
            //
        }


    }
```

In this service get method I am calling webapi method Login through url paramater. But the concern is I am receiving data :

```
{{"code": "200", "message": "hello Sarker", "status": "OK"}}
```

which format is invalid json because there is two extra { }braces in front and end.

I will appreciate all of your help.

Thanks

U.Sarker

Comment: What is throwing the exception mentioned in your title?

Comment: when I deserialize  using "JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(apiVal); " inside try catch giving me exception in xamarin form.cs

Comment: after all day exploring I found different solution to consume correct formatted json data from webapi  to my rest service class and deserialize to the Model class. Gracias